# I need a program that can auto-tag my MP3s and sort them into folders

Tags: mp3, music, tags, id3

I'm looking for a program that can go through the 5GB of MP3s in my `Unsorted` folder, automatically fill in ID3 tags and album art, rename the files and sort them into new folders like so:

`M:\Temp\Artist Name\Album Name\Artist Name - Song Name.mp4`

(it should create the `Artist Name` and `Album Name` folders by itself)

I googled around and found [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard) and [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/index.html), both of which I tried without any success. If fact, I'm not sure what happened in Mp3tag but it changed the artist and album for all the MP3s!

Are there better (i.e. noob friendly) tools to do this? And if Picard/Mp3tag are the right tools for the job, can you please link me to some good tutorials?

Comment: How do you want it to work out the values for the ID3 tags? Mp3Tag is a really good program: If you have the tags it can sort out the folder/file names, and if you have the folder/file names it can sort out the tags. But if you have niether, I don't see where the information can come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm. I've used Mp3tag on Windows and now using Picard on FreeBSD, and find them quite good (Mp3tag is a bit better, imho). Unfortunately, there is no tool which can fill the tags for these famous Unsorted mp3's fully automated. This action requires your attention anyway, but both programs you mentioned can give you much help with this.
Once you have all tags filled, moving and renaming files is easy. In Picard it's a last part of tags lookup process. You should set the target directory and renaming rule in settings (see http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Picard_Documentation/Options and http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/Picard_Tags) and then save your files.
With Mp3tag, you should click Tag->Filename button and enter/confirm the renaming rule (guide is here: http://help.mp3tag.de/main_converter.html#ttf)

Answer (score 3):

A while back I used Jaikoz (http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz/).

Main benefit imho: "... Many of the songs also have an Acoustic Id provided by Acoustid, allowing a song to be identified by the actual music, so it can do a match even if you have no metadata! ..."

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer I am the developer of SongKong)

http://jthink.net/songkong is designed to do exactly this, its very easy so I'll explain how you do it.

- Download and install SongKong from http://jthink.net/songkong/download.jsp
- Start SongKong
- Drag C:\Temp to SongKong
- Click on the Fix Songs icon (first icon)
- Select the 'Rename files based on metadata when matched' option
- Click on the Filenaming tab
- Change the **Compilation Rename Mask** and the **Rename Mask**  to the **'AlbumArtistOrArtist/Album/TrackArtist - Title'** option
- Click Start

The SongKong will do it thing and at the end create a report showing exactly what has been matched and changed.

Comment: How to you make it automatically monitor watch and apply metadata? For example, I want all songs in my "K-Pop" folder to have the "genre" label to "K-Pop" but there's no option in SongKong to type "K-Pop" but rather select from a list?